# Docker hostnames are not resolved in a custom network

Tags: docker, networking, dns, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following configuration in my `docker-composer.yml` file.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  service-1:
    container_name: 'service-1'
    build: './service-1'
    depends_on:
      - 'mongo'
      - 'consul'
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - service-1
  service-2:
    build: './service-2'
    ports:
      - '8825:8825'
      - '8835:8835'
    networks:
      frontend:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - service-2
    depends_on:
      - 'mongo'
      - 'consul'
  consul:
    image: 'consul:latest'
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - consul
  mongo:
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - mongo

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
    internal: true
```

When my containers start they are not able to communicate between each other using host names. 
Most of containers use the mongo db container, but they are not able even reach it and I am getting the following error.

```
Error connecting to mongo : no reachable servers
```

Please help me to solve the problem, I got stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of unneeded settings in the compose file, here's a stripped down version that would work just as well:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  service-1:
    build: './service-1'
    networks:
      - backend
  service-2:
    build: './service-2'
    ports:
      - '8825:8825'
      - '8835:8835'
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
  consul:
    image: 'consul:latest'
    networks:
      - backend
  mongo:
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
    internal: true
```

You automatically get the alias of the service name for each container, no need to duplicate that. You also lose the ability to scale a service if you give it a container name. I'd also recommend moving the build step out of the compose file and use an image name for the apps you're building locally.

---

Now for the likely issue, you have a depends_on in your compose file. At best, this will not do what you're looking for. All it checks that the other container has been created and started, but not that the application inside is ready to serve traffic, and a DB may take time to become available. At worst, you'll get an error that it's unsupported if you try to move this into swarm mode.

Instead of depending on docker for this, update your application entrypoint to check for the external dependencies and wait a minute or two for them to become available before failing. A very simple example tool for this is [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) that is written as a bash shell script.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have already tried this config, however this won't work as well, hosts are still not reachable

Comment: @bxfvgekd the yml file was not the answer to the question. Please update your question with the modified entrypoint, and logs from both containers.